# Active is not updating. After a hot reload it is active react native

Tags: react-native

My child component is below

```
export default function PickerList    ({headingText,listData,hideView,finalpickedItem,onItemSelected,selected} ) {
         const {modalHolder,modalHeader,modalHeaderText,modalBody,PerListView,PerListVie wText,okCancel,okCancelHolder,PerListViewActive,
     } = styles;

      return(
        <View style={modalHolder}>
          <View style={modalHeader}>
            <Text style={modalHeaderText}>{headingText}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={modalBody}>
            <FlatList data={listData} renderItem={({item , index}) =>
                <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    {headingText === 'name'?
                      onItemSelected(item.name)
                    : headingText === 'Time' ?
                      onItemSelected(item.time)
                    : headingText === 'Property'
                      onItemSelected(item.property)
                    }
                  }}
                  style={{width:'100%',}}
                  >
                  <View
                    style={
                      selected===item.name ? PerListViewActive : PerListView > // here i am not getting active hot reload making it active
                    <Text style={PerListViewText}>
                    {item.name }
                  </Text></View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              }
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    };

    PickerList.propTypes = {
      onItemSelected: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };
```

and my parent is

```
onMenuItemSelected = item => {
      console.log(item); // i am getting here selected item
      this.setState({ commonSelected: item }); // i am getting final state also.
  }

<PickerList
  headingText="Property"
  listData = {this.state.property_type_options}
  hideView = {()=>{this.hideView()}}
  finalpickedItem = {()=>{this.finalpickedItem()}}
  onItemSelected={this.onMenuItemSelected}
  selected = {this.state.commonSelected} /// i have final value here also
/>
```

issue is "selected" not working every thing is working fine .. selected working but after a hot reload. can i re-render module. state is updating fine but it is not getting active.

Comment: Should i add more elaboration .. is it understandable. ??

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer this is very nice.

extraData={this.state}